# How to relate a "parent common" table with its (possibly many) "subtype" tables?

Tags: database-design, subtypes

I am having a bit of a brain freeze. I have a table whose properties are the *root* of four distinct elements, for example:

- I need to relate `SystemType` to a `SystemCommon`, where one `SystemCommon` can have only one of the subtypes. How do I do this?

Should I add a `SubType` table and then add a `SubTypeID` to each `SystemType`?

```
CREATE TABLE SystemCommon (
    ID    int identity(1,1) not null,
    Name  varchar(20) not null,
    Descriptor  varchar(20) not null,
    CommonInfo  varchar(20) not null
    CONSTRAINT   PK_Parent Primary Key CLUSTERED (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE SystemType1 (
    ID                  int identity(1,1) not null,
    UniqueSystem1Field  varchar(100) not null
    CONSTRAINT   PK_SystemType1 Primary Key CLUSTERED (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE SystemType2 (
    ID                  int identity(1,1) not null,
    UniqueSystem2Field  varchar(100) not null
    CONSTRAINT   PK_SystemType2 Primary Key CLUSTERED (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE SystemType3 (
    ID                  int identity(1,1) not null,
    UniqueSystem3Field  varchar(100) not null
    CONSTRAINT   PK_SystemType3 Primary Key CLUSTERED (ID)
)
```

**Clarifications for comment requests:**

1. Perhaps "Parent" is really a poor choice of wording, and "SystemCommon" might be better.

   a. `SystemCommon` is a table that contains columns that are common to **all** `SystemTypes`.

   b. `SystemTypes` are the unique parameters for each of the `SystemTypes` - each `SystemType` is its own table. There are four `Types` currently.

   c. A `SystemCommon` can have only one `SystemType` (any 1 of the 4).

   d. Many `SystemCommons` can have the same `SystemType`. So `SystemType1` can belong to `SystemCommon` (where id=1..n).

I am trying to model accordingly. A main group of elements that correlates to a given *system* (just for example as it is the best analogy I can come up with)
A *computer* has a `Name` and an `IpAddress` (all *computers* - `SystemCommon`). Each of these *computers* can have *program[x1]* or a *program [x2]* or a *program[x3]* but it can have **only one** of those *program types*, but it can have as many instances of that *program type* as it likes (so this is a one-to-many relationship); the hard part is to relate which `SystemType` (*x1*, or *x2* or *x3*). It seems like a case of inheritance, as suggested via comments.

Comment: Still not entirely clear. Shall we assume that a row in `Parent` (SystemCommon) be related to many rows in a child table (`SystemTypeX`) but all theses children should be in the same `X`?

Comment: @ypercube A column of a row in SystemCommon (Parent) needs to refer to the specific SystemType  Table [Which Table] AND Which Row of that Specific table.

Comment: I was expecting a Yes (to many rows) or No (only to one row) answer.

Comment: @StixO: If you are struggling with making your verbal description perfectly clear and unambiguous, perhaps you could update your question with examples (data samples) illustrating what is and what isn't possible in the set-up you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Andriy M : case of inheritance - yes much like that. Thanks for jogging my mind I should have included that wording..